# Data pipeline for running data records through modules which are acyclically dependent on each other

Tags: database, data-structures, architecture, pipeline, data-processing

My question revolves around the best practice for processing data through multiple modules, where each module creates new data from the original data or from data generated by other modules. Let me create an illustrative example, where I'll be considering a MongoDB document and modules which create update parameters for the document. Consider a base document, `{"a":2}`. Now, consider these modules, which I've written as Python functions:

```py
def mod1(data):
    a = data["a"]
    b = 2 * a
    return {"$set":{"b":b}}

def mod2(data):
    b = data["b"]
    c = "Good" if b > 1 else "Bad"
    return {"$set":{"c":c}}

def mod3(data):
    a = data["a"]
    d = a - 3
    return {"$set":{"d":d}}

def mod4(data):
    c = data["c"]
    d = data["d"]
    e = d if c == "Good" else 0
    return {"$set":{"e":e}}
```

When applied in the correct order, the updated document will be `{"a":2,"b":4,"c":"Good","d":-1,"e":-1}`. Note that `mod1` and `mod3` can run simultaneously, while `mod4` must wait for `mod2` and `mod3` to run on a document. My question is more general though; what's the best way to do something like this? My current method is very similar to this, but with each module getting its own Docker container due to the less trivial nature of their processing. The problem with this is that it requires every module to be querying the entire collection in which these documents reside continuously to see if documents become valid for them to process.

Answer (score 0):

You really want an event-driven architecture for this for pipelines like this.  As records are updated, push events onto a topic queue (or [ESB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus)) and have the other pipelines listening to those queues.  As events are published, those other pipeline stages can pick up records and process their stages.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to reply, but what happens if one of the modules goes down? How does it handle multiple processes for the same module? Is there a good resource on any of this?